# how do i save time in datagridview in vb.net 2010 [Newbie student]

Tags: vb.net-2010

Example i press start time and the time connected in textbox that it will show when i start the time same with out time,and when i press save it wont add to datagridview. Please help me with my problem. This is my save code:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    Table1BindingSource.AddNew()
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Update(Me.OpenDataSet.Table1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved your problem....

Here is how your form should look like :

[image]

And now you need to add the "Time" columns to the datagridview:

[image]

And now... follow my steps through the image:

[image]

and here is the code :

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Table1BindingSource.Rows.Add()
    Table1BindingSource.Rows(Table1BindingSource.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value = TextBox1.Text & Table1BindingSource.Rows.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CountTimer.Tick
    TextBox1.Text += 1
End Sub
End Class
```

I Hope My Answer Was Useful To You :)

Comment: thank you :), i got question again example in my textbox i write time like hh:mm:ss then it will save to database what code do i put in?

Comment: Did you made the database table, i mean : is the database file ready to use in visual basic, or not?

Comment: yes i already make, the problem is cant save just a blank field

Comment: OK, but i think that i can't help you with some texts or pictures in this, so i prefer to watch a tutorial video instead, you can see this video... i think it will help you to do what do you want to do [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqqCbAGDZWk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqqCbAGDZWk), but if you still have some problems... just feel free to ask ;)